# Reference vs. Callback (provider/factory)

Tags: c#, callback, reference

I try to understand some concepts, but I can't do it by myself, so guys I need your help.
I try to understand what's the difference between a reference and a callback, may this term is not the perfect one, I try to understand this code:

What's the difference in the initialization of a member variable with a method from class A and a method from class B?

```
    class A
    {
        private BlockingCollection<int> _collectionA;

        public void SetA(ref BlockingCollection<int> collectionA)
        {
            _collectionA = collectionA;
        }
    }

    class B
    {
        private BlockingCollection<int> _collectionB;

        public void SetB(Func<BlockingCollection<int>> collectionBProvider)
        {
            _collectionB = collectionBProvider();
        }
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
            BlockingCollection<int> bCollection = new BlockingCollection<int>(boundedCapacity: 20);

            A a = new A();
            a.SetA(ref bCollection);

            B b = new B();
            b.SetB(() => bCollection);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, both SetA and SetB methods can be used to access and modify the initial list that was passed in as an argument, regardless of whether it was passed by reference or using a callback.

In the case of SetA, the list is passed by reference using the ref keyword, so any modifications made to the list inside the method will be reflected in the original list that was passed in.

In the case of SetB, the list is obtained using a callback that returns the initial list, so any modifications made to the list that was obtained from the callback will also be reflected in the original list.

So, both methods allow you to access and modify the initial list, but they use different mechanisms to do so.